# Returning array or List of models from form in Razor View to action on Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on a learning project in which I created a view which displays a list of Delisted Books( isActive = false) populated by calling an api.
The view has a list of books + a checkbox in front of each book so that upon clicking the books we want to set active and hit the save button, it returns the books which are selected to the action in controller.
This is the view I am working with :

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcBooksList.Models.Book>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delisted Books";
}


@if (Model != null)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DelistedForm", "Book", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm" }))
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookName)
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Publisher)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Enlist
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookName)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.BookName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Author)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Publisher)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Publisher)

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />    <input type = "button" value = "Cancel" onclick = "location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'" />

        }

    }
    else
    {
    <h3>No Books currently delisted</h3>
}
```

This is the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MvcBooksList.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Subcategory { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public double? Price { get; set; }
        public int Pages { get; set; }
        public string AddedBy { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is the controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DelistedForm(IEnumerable<Book> fromDelist)
        {
            foreach (var item in fromDelist)
            {
                if (item.IsActive == true)
                //CALL
                {
                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = baseAddressOfBookApi;
                        var resopnse = await client.GetAsync("Book/EnlistBook?id="+item.BookName.ToString());
                        if (!resopnse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        { 
                            return View(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
```

Dont mind the code inside the action.

So when I press the submit button nothing gets passed to the action. The fromDelist collection is showing a count of 0.
So ,what am I doing wrong.
And Is it possible that I can return the names of books that are checked.

BookController ::

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MvcBooksList.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MvcBooksList.Controllers
{
    public class BookController : Controller
    {
        readonly Uri baseAddressOfBookApi;
        public BookController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            baseAddressOfBookApi = new Uri(configuration.GetSection("ApiAddress:BookAPI").Value);
        }


        /* 
         public ActionResult Edit(string name)
         {

             return View(name); //repalce with the name of view
         }

         public ActionResult Delete(string name)
         {
             return View(name);  //repalce with the name of view
         }

         public ActionResult Delist(string name)
         {
             return View(name);   //repalce with the name of view
         }
        */

        public async Task<ActionResult> ViewDelistedBooks()
        {
            List<Book> bookdetails = new List<Book>();
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = baseAddressOfBookApi;
                var response = await client.GetAsync("Book/ViewDelistedBooks");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var BookResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    bookdetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Book>>(BookResponse);
                }
            }
            return View(bookdetails);
        }

        public ActionResult Cancel()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DelistedForm(IEnumerable<Book> fromDelist)
        {
            foreach (var item in fromDelist)
            {
                if (item.IsActive == true)
                //CALL
                {
                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = baseAddressOfBookApi;
                        var resopnse = await client.GetAsync("Book/EnlistBook?id="+item.BookName.ToString());
                        if (!resopnse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        { 
                            return View(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller too, pls?

Comment: And try to remove new { @id = "myForm" } . What do you need it for?

Comment: @Serge , I just added BookController, 
And yeah sry for that , I'll remove it as I am not using it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace foreach by for

```
@model List<MvcBooksList.Models.Book>

 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i+=1)
{
 ......
             
                       <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model[i].Publisher)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Publisher)

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].IsActive)
                        </td>
                    </tr>

.... and so on for all
```

and replace a table header

```
<th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].BookName)
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Author)
                    </th>
```

Comment: It says  :  Error CS0021 Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IEnumerable<Book>' MvcBooksList

Comment: I updated my answer. Replace IEnumerable by List.

Comment: Woah , it worked . Thanks for the awesome answer. Really appreciate it..